# Java Stream Filter based on a Set-type

Tags: java, filter, collections, set, java-stream

Is there any way to filter a Set field in a Stream or List based on a Set using Lambda Stream?

Example:

```
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    Set<String> hobbySet1 = new HashSet<String>();
    hobbySet1.add("H1");
    hobbySet1.add("H2");
    hobbySet1.add("H3");

    Set<String> hobbySet2 = new HashSet<String>();
    hobbySet2.add("H2");
    hobbySet2.add("H4");

    Set<String> hobbySet3 = new HashSet<String>();
    hobbySet3.add("H3");

    Set<String> hobbySet4 = new HashSet<String>();
    hobbySet4.add("H4");

    persons.add(new Person("P1", hobbySet1));
    persons.add(new Person("P2", hobbySet2));
    persons.add(new Person("P3", hobbySet3));
    persons.add(new Person("P4", hobbySet4));

    Set<String> searchHobby = new HashSet<String>();
    searchHobby.add("H1");
    searchHobby.add("H3");
```

I want to filter hobbies from List persons based on searchHobby, so that only those persons who have their hobbies specified in searchHobby will be retained.

I know how to achieve this using a simple for loop.

```
    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();

    for (String sHobby : searchHobby) {
        for (Person p : persons) {
            Set<String> pHobbySet = p.getHobbies();
            for (String pHobby : pHobbySet) {
                if (pHobby.equalsIgnoreCase(sHobby)) {
                    Optional<Person> wasAdded = result.stream().filter(s->s.getName()==p.getName()).findAny();
                    if(wasAdded.isEmpty()) {
                        result.add(p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

***I'm looking for a java Stream Filter solution.***

---

P.S. **Person**

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    Set<String> hobbies;

    public Person(String name, Set<String> hobbies) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public Set<String> getHobbies(){
        return hobbies;
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<Person> collect = persons.stream().filter(s -> s.getHobbies().containsAll(searchHobby))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Note that in your example `hobbySet3 ` and `hobbySet4` are empty

Comment: @Ruslan, I corrected example [hobbySet3] and [hobbySet4], thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) will return true if some hobby matches.

```
List<Person> personsWithHobby = persons.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getHobbies().stream()
            .anyMatch(searchHobby::contains))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [containsAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-) method to find a person who's hobbies contain all `searchHobby`:

```
List<Person> collect = persons.stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getHobbies().containsAll(searchHobby))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you need to find persons where at least one person's hobby is in `searchHobbies` then you could use [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
List<Person> collect = persons.stream()
            .filter(person -> new HashSet<>(person.getHobbies()).removeAll(searchHobby))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: removeAll would change the persons hobbies wouldn't it?

Comment: @Nicktar that's why I wrapped this in `new HashSet<>(...)`. In that case original hobbies won't be changed

Comment: the first filter is same as Vishwa Ratna suggested. the second get same result as Red_Shuhart's, exectly meet my for...loop requirement. Thank you everybody! I learnt a lot:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```java
persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getHobbies().stream()
            .filter(searchHobby::contains)
            .findAny().isPresent()
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loops do handle the conditions a bit awkward, suboptimal.
A simple solution would be:

```
List<Person> result = persons.stream()
       .filter(p -> hasHobby(p.getHobbies(), searchHobby))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

boolean hasHobby(Set<String> personHobbies, Set<String> searchHobbies) {
    Set<String> pH = personHobbiers.stream()
            .map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<String> sH = searchHobbiers.stream()
            .map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return !pH.retainAll(sh).isEmpty();
}
```

This is suboptimal too. Especially it is a pitty that one needs an ignore-case.
And simply taking an intersection is hard. However with a couple of hobbies this should not be hard. One could lowercase `searchHobbies` at the start.